# How to inject CakePHP 3 validations into form when using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I have an application that currently has the user click a membership level which will display data for that membership and allow the user to add 1 or 2 users depending on the membership as well as pay using Stripe. The user forms submit to a different controller action, but the Stripe payment goes to the current controller, but also a different action.

I would like to be able to halt the AJAX and display validation errors (if any) for the user forms. So far, this code (thanks to @Kevin B) will grab and contain the errors in the AJAX data (it displays in console.log), but I am unsure how to display it in the forms.

I have searched and found a couple examples for earlier versions of CakePHP, but I don't know if they are the proper route with CakePHP 3. They also seem fairly different than what I am trying to do, so I don't know if they would even work.

- [Example 1](http://jamnite.blogspot.com/2009/05/cakephp-form-validation-with-ajax-using.html)
- [Example 2](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/)

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$(function() {
    var submitAllForms = function() {
        var promiseArr = $('#userForm, #secondUserForm').map(function() {
            var formDetails = $(this);
            return $.ajax({
                type: formDetails.attr('method'),
                url: formDetails.attr('action'),
                data: formDetails.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('user\(s\) have been added');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('user\(s\) could not be added');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }).get();
        // wait until both of the other forms' data are submitted
        //$.when.apply(null, promiseArr).then(function () {
        //    $('#payment-form').get(0).submit();
        //});
    }
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<?= $keys[0]['publishable_key'] ?>');
    $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        $form = $(this);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        //async
        Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(response);
            if(response.error) {
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                var token = response.id;
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken"/>').val(token));
                submitAllForms();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Sample data in console.log:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Join Now</h1>
        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/utahreia3.0/users/add">
            <div style="display:none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
            </div>
            <div class="input text">
                <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="full_name" maxlength="100" id="full-name" value="mr dude">
            </div>
            <div class="input text error">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" id="username" class="form-error" value="mrdude">
                <div class="error-message">That username has already been used.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="input email error">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="100" id="email" class="form-error" value="mr@dude.com">
                <div class="error-message">That email has already been used.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="input password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Skater1">
            </div>
            <div class="input password error">
                <label for="password-confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation" class="form-error" value="Skter1">
                <div class="error-message">Passwords do not match.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="input select required">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <select name="role" required="required" id="role">
                    <option value="1">Admin</option>
                    <option value="2">Editor</option>
                    <option value="3">Author</option>
                    <option value="4" selected="selected">Reader</option>
                </select>
            </div>
                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the form for the users/add view is what is displayed, but I am in the membership_levels/checkout/2 view. Should I just replace the forms with the one that is returned? Or is there a better way? It is also returned in straight html, should it be JSON? If so, I can't figure out how to get the form in JSON, I can get the user data that is submitted in JSON, but not the returned form.

Comment: Sounds more like a JavaScript problem to me, like "How to inject data into an HTML element". What your question is missing, is a description of the actual technical problem that you are facing.

Comment: You could be right... I just know that CakePHP 3 has built in validation and it works if I am going directly to the users/add view for instance. Since I am in a different controller action and am posting the data via ajax it doesn't actually go to that view, so I lose the feedback for the user. I was wondering if there was a simple way to stop the ajax processing if there are any validation errors and display them as if I was accessing the users/add view directly either with a JSON response or some other means.